# How to insert UIButtons into UITextView as a list

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I'm having a UITextView and also a scrollView with UIButtons, now I would like to add those UIButtons which are placed inside the scrollView into the UITextView. now everytime i do `uitextview.addSubview(uibutton)` it adds all the uibuttons inside the same first place and it overloads each other..
Here's a picture of how it looks like: [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7GrY.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

UITextView is not designed for what you are trying to do. Whenever you call `.addSubview`, all it's going to do is use the UIButton's `.frame` to decide where to place the button.

All of your button's frames will be defaulted to `CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, ...)`, so they will all be added to the same point 0,0 in the textview.

To achieve the look you want, you would need to iterate over the list of buttons, and adjust the X / Y attributes based on the size of the previous button. Also taking into account when the button would be too wide to fit, and would need to go to the next line. And adjust for screen rotations etc.

I'd recommend looking at already built open source controls like these two, rather than trying to build it all from scratch:

- https://github.com/ElaWorkshop/TagListView
- https://github.com/popodidi/HTagView

Comment: I see, isnt working with UITextField is much better? cause i dont want to use 3rd party :\

Comment: @AviavSabag no, the textfield only has special support for a subview to be placed on the right side. Adding more than one, or wanting to fill the control with many, will have exactly the same issue. I would question why you "don't want to use 3rd party", unless they don't support something you need, you are going to make a lot of work for yourself for no reason